# How to check if an equation has numbers with multiple digits

Tags: java, string, numbers, infix-notation

We are making a program to convert an input from infix to postfix. This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Stack;

public class InfixToPostfix
{
    public static int Precedence(char c)
    {
        return switch (c) {
            case '+', '-' -> 1;
            case '*', '/' -> 2;
            default -> -1;
        };
    }

    public static boolean isOp(char c)
    {
        return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/';
    }


    public static void convert()
    {
        JFrame f;
        f = new JFrame();
        String eq = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Equation");

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        String postfix = "";
        String numberInProgress = "";

        for(int i=0; i<eq.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = eq.charAt(i);
        
            if(Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                numberInProgress += c;
            }


            if(i>0 && Character.isDigit(eq.charAt(i-1)) && !Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                postfix += numberInProgress;
            }
                
            if(Character.isLetter(c))
                postfix += (c + " ");
            
            else if(isOp(c)) //Performs operator precedence stack checking/pushing/adding to String
            {
                if(stack.isEmpty())
                    stack.push(c);
                else if(Precedence(c) > Precedence(stack.peek()))
                    stack.push(c);
                else if(Precedence(c) <= Precedence(stack.peek()))
                {
                    postfix += (stack.pop() + " ");
                    stack.push(c);
                }

            }
            else if(c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{') //This else if and while perform the actions when a set of paranthesis is completed
                stack.push(c);
            while((c == ')' && stack.peek() != '(') || (c == ']' && stack.peek() != '[') || (c == '}' && stack.peek() != '{') )
            {
                if(stack.peek()=='(' || stack.peek()=='[' || stack.peek()=='{' )
                    stack.pop();
                else
                    postfix += (stack.pop() + " ");
            }

        }
        if(stack.peek()=='(' || stack.peek()=='[' || stack.peek()=='{' ) //Simply removes if the top of the stack is a parenthesis
                stack.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i <=stack.size() ; i++) //Finishes of the stack once the string is finished being iterated through
        {
            if(stack.peek()=='(' || stack.peek()=='[' || stack.peek()=='{' )
                stack.pop();
            if(stack.size()==0)
                break;
            postfix += (stack.pop() + " ");

        }
    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, postfix);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        convert();
    }

}
```

it works with variables and numbers that are only one digit but if i want to do 12+3, it would output 1 2 3+ when I really want it to output 12 3 + I then need to make a calculator to calculate the postfix string but I think that would be easier than what I am trying to do right now. I just need to somehow get this to recognize numbers that are more than one digit. UPDATE: I tried to do what Ian Mc suggested and I am so close but I just cannot figure it out. 12+3 with this current code outputs 12+ so I can get it to recognize double digits at least

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to process multi-digit numbers because you don't maintain the state of the number as you read the equation character by character.  The following code is the root of the problem:

```
if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
    postfix += (c + " ");
```

One way to maintain state is to introduce a new variable: `String numberInProgress = "";`

If you process a digit, you change the state: `numberInProgress += c;`.   You do not process the number at this point; go on and read the next character from the equation.

When you hit any character that is not a number (a bracket, operation, space), you finalize `numberInProgress`, and proceed to process it.  After that, reset `numberInProgress = ""`.